# Do I need to synchronize even if two threads don't read and write simultaneously?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, volatile, atomic

In a Java program, suppose a variable is being written by one thread (say, T1) and the same variable is being read by another thread (say, T2) but not simultaneously. So, when I know T2 will read only after T1 has written (how that's done is a different matter), do I still need to declare that variable as volatile/synchronize it/use AtomicReference?

I guess there would be slightest of the possibilities that T2 will end up reading stale value at few instances?

Comment: *when I know T2 will read only after T1 has written (how that's done is a different matter)*. No, it's actually critical to the question. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

**It depends on how you ensure that T2 will read only after T1 has been written.** If you have a proper happens-before relationship between the write and the read, the operation is safe.

Refer to [chapter 17.4 of the Java 7 specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) (or the corresponding section in the newer docs) for details. Happens-before is transitive and

> If an action x synchronizes-with a following action y, then we also have hb(x, y).

That is, if you have an independent synchronization primitive ensuring a happens-before relationship after the read and before the write, your read is safe.